# usb4java on windows 10

Tags: java, windows-10, usb4java

I want to code a USB-Locker for any OS using usb4java. I can list all my devices, but if I want to use the [HotPlug class](https://github.com/usb4java/usb4java-examples/blob/master/src/main/java/org/usb4java/examples/HotPlug.java) made by Klaus Reimer I get the informaion:

"libusb doesn't support hotplug on this system"

Is there an alternitiv class, or an user code to do the same thing as the [HotPlug class](https://github.com/usb4java/usb4java-examples/blob/master/src/main/java/org/usb4java/examples/HotPlug.java).
I am working on Windows 10 and it should run on this os as well, so programming in Linux or so is not an option to avoid this error.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I used the same example and had the same notification. Now I´m using usb4java-javax in version 1.2.0 and it works like this:

```
final UsbServices services = UsbHostManager.getUsbServices();
final UsbDeviceService usbDeviceService = new UsbDeviceService();

services.addUsbServicesListener(new UsbServicesListener() {
        public void usbDeviceAttached(UsbServicesEvent usbServicesEvent) {}
        public void usbDeviceDetached(UsbServicesEvent usbServicesEvent) {}
}
```

Be sure your application is running all the time.